# Best way to create simple web server for python files

Tags: python, webserver

I need to access my python programs through IP address for making it to do something in server. Creating Apache Server for only one python script is not good solution.
In server it works like: `python script.py --arg`

Now I need something like `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/script.py --arg` or something else. Main idea is to send argument to program remotely without ssh.

PS. Main problem with framework and python simple HTTP server was block in firewall.

Comment: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

Comment: @Puciek already tried, not works, after first line starting on 0.0.0.0 nothing comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/) and make your script logic in a web service to call it using the IP and send to it the arguments.
and to make it running using the global IP you can use something like WSGI (http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Example:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/script_name")
def script_name():
    #Taking the arguments.
    arg1 = device_id = ast.literal_eval(request.data)['arg1']
    #Complete the logic here.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

With Flask you can do that in about ten lines of code.

Comment: Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
Noting else coming, global ip not working.